# C# ApplicationContext usage

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

Apologies if my terminology is off, I'm new to C#.  I'm trying to use an ApplicationContext file to store mysql conn values, like dbname, username, password.  The class with mysql conn string is "using" the namespace for the ApplicationContext, but when I print out the connection string, the values are making it.

A friend said, "I'm not initializing it" but couldn't stay to expand on what "it" was.

and the "Console.WriteLine("1");" in ApplicationContext.cs never shows up.  Do I need to create an ApplicationContext object and the call Initialize() on that object?

Thanks for any help.

ApplicationContext.cs:

```
namespace NewApplication.Context
{
    class ApplicationContext
    {
        public static string serverName;
        public static string username;
        public static string password;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //need to read through config here

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("1");
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load(".\\Settings.xml");
                XmlNodeList serverNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DatabaseServer");
                XmlNodeList usernameNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("UserName");
                XmlNodeList passwordNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Password");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                //TODO: Future write to log file
                username = "user";
                password = "password";
                serverName = "localhost";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MySQLManager.cs:
note: dbname is the same as the username as you'll see in the code, I copied this from a friend who does that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using NewApplication.Context;


namespace NewApplication.DAO
{
    class MySQLManager
    {
        private static MySqlConnection conn;
        public static MySqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            if (conn == null || conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                string connStr = "server=" + ApplicationContext.serverName +
                    ";user=" + ApplicationContext.username + ";database=" + ApplicationContext.username + ";port=3306;password=" +
                    ApplicationContext.password + ";";
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL... ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection string:  " + connStr + "\n");
                    conn.Open();
                    // Perform databse operations


                    // conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

and, thanks for still reading, this is the code that uses the two previous files:

```
class LogDAO
{
    MySqlConnection conn;

    public LogDAO()
    {
        conn = MySQLManager.getConnection();
}
```

Thank you,
rd42

Comment: There's already an ApplicationContext class... so what are you trying to do with yours?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring that there's already a very rich set of Configuration Classes in .NET including ones for [Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) that support encryption, you do need to as some point call Application.Initialize() in order for it fields to be populated.

I should mention that this looks like an implementation of a singleton. You might want to read Jon Skeet's [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on singletons because there are probably things you want to watch out for. For example what would happen if two threads called ApplicationContext.Initialize()? Are multiple calls to ApplicationContext.Initialize() even sensible?

Also public fields are probably a bad idea especially when you have [automatic implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm inheriting a project and they want changes yesterday and I'm new to C.  I will check out the links, and thanks for the Application.Initialize() hint.